# How much do data structures contribute towards ink contract storage size?

Tags: ink, storage

I've used `Mapping`, `BTreeSet`, `BTreeMap` and `Vec` for various purposes in our ink contract and have observed the contract size fluctuating based on usage of these four data structures. This leads me to the question of what data structures are best in regards to reducing contract size?

We currently have a 128KB contract size limit which I have hit many times now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a bunch of benchmarking [here](https://github.com/goastler/ink_contract_size_benchmark). This takes an empty ink contract and adds data structures to the contract storage, observing the change in contract size under debug and release conditions. Here's an excerpt:

### Results

Takeaways (from release contract size):

- an empty contract is 0.8KB

#### Importing (i.e. 1 use of the data structure in the contract storage)

- importing `Vec` is 2KB
- importing `BTreeSet` is 8.3KB
- importing `BTreeMap` is 9.1KB
- importing `BTreeMap` and `BTreeSet` is 16.1KB, which is less than their combined sizes so there is some shared code here
- a single `Mapping` takes 0.5KB

#### Additional (i.e. 2 uses of the data structure in the contract storage)

- adding another `Vec` adds 2.3KB
- adding another `BTreeSet` adds 0.4KB
- adding another `BTreeMap` adds 0.5KB, so `BTreeMap` is slightly heavier than `BTreeSet`
- adding another `Mapping` takes 0.6KB

#### As the value type of `Mapping` (on top of the 0.5KB for a `Mapping` in the first place) (e.g. `Mapping<AccountId, BTreeSet<AccountId>>`)

- a `Mapping` with `Vec` adds 0.6KB
- a `Mapping` with `BTreeSet` adds ~0KB (I think this is small because a lot of the `BTreeSet` functionality is not used due to it being the value of a `Mapping`, and therefore removed from the contract)
- a `Mapping` with `BTreeMap` adds 0.4KB

#### Comparison

- `Mapping` is a lot lighter-weight than `BTreeSet` or `BTreeMap` to import (I imagine this is because `Mapping` is always compiled into the contract, so is present in the empty contract and importing it does not do anything. This is supported by the single `Mapping` contract increase being almost equal to that of adding another `Mapping` above)
- adding additional `Mapping`, `BTreeSet` or `BTreeMap` increases contract size by ~0.5KB for each
- adding additional `Vec` is rather expensive at 2.3KB each, but the original import is much smaller than `BTreeSet` or `BTreeMap`
- having data structures like `Vec`, `BTreeSet` or `BTreeMap` loaded via a `Mapping` costs less than having them in the contract storage directly. (I imagine this is because much of their functionality can be optimised away based on their usage)

| Type | Import size (KB) | Usage size (KB) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Mapping` | 0.5 | 0.6 |
| `BTreeSet` | 8.7 | 0.4 |
| `BTreeMap` | 9.1 | 0.5 |
| `Vec` | 2 | 2.3 |

- import size is the cost of using only 1 of the data structure
- usage size is the cost of each additional use of the data structure

### Tldr;

- Avoiding `BTreeSet` or `BTreeMap` can save ~10KB
- Each `Vec` cost ~2KB
- Use `Mapping` (or `BTreeSet` or `BTreeMap` if already in use elsewhere) over `Vec` where possible to save ~1.5KB
- Adding additional `Mapping`, `BTreeSet` or `BTreeMap` all cost approximately the same amount (~0.5KB)
- Lazy load `BTreeSet`, `BTreeMap` and `Vec` to save ~0.6KB at most
- Using five or more `BTreeSet`s or `BTreeMap`s is more cost-effective than using `Vec`s overall
- Using less than five `Vec`s is more cost-effective than using `BTreeSet`s or `BTreeMap`s overall